# Search for first occurrence of a string and insert string on line above with python

Tags: python

I usually work in bash so i'm very new to this frightening world of python.

I am attempting to search a file for a string then insert text above the "First occurrence" of that string with empty line between.

The file to be edited would look like this:

```
Name:

Billy

Thorton

Billy

Thorton
```

I am trying to insert "Bob" above "Thorton" with the empty lines between like this:

```
Name:

Billy

Bob

Thorton

Billy

Thorton
```

This is the Python i have so far.

```
contents = "Bob"
f = open("file", "w")
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

This does not search for the string and it replaces the whole file.

A working example in bash would be:

```
sed  -i '0,/Thorton/s//Bob\n\n&/' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do so in Python would be to open the file, iterate over it line by line and prepare the results, then write the results to the file.

```py
res = ""

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines() # Read the file line by line

found = False    
for line in data:
    if "Thorton" in line and not found:
        res += "Bob\n\n" # Insert Bob if needed
        found = True
    res += line # Insert the line we just read

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(res) # Write the answer in the same file
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question. I was looking for a solution to insert after the first occurrence of a string. The example worked but it inserts after every occurrence of Billy. If you could please amend the answer for my new edit. This was an error of mine sorry.

Comment: You can just use a variable to prevent inserting again. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.split()` to get each item into a list then use `list.index()` to get the position of `"Thorton"` to insert from then `str.join()` to get them back into writable form:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read().split()
data.insert(data.index('Thorton'), 'Bob')
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n\n'.join(data))
```

Comment: The problem i have with this approach is if there is ever a format to the file it destroys that format.

Comment: That’s true although in keeping with the example you have then this works fine

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
searchedName = "Thorton"
addedName= "Bob"
f = open("file", "w")
content = f.readlines()
index = content.index(searchedName + '\n')
contents = content.insert(index , addedName + '\n')
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```